# How do you save a result of a program in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm making a program in python with a list inside where every time you run the program, one element of the list gets randomly selected and deleted.

My problem is that i want to save the new list and get that list the next time i run the program.
How do i do that?

Comment: can you provide your tried code and an example of your list before deletion and after ?

Comment: there are loads of formats that can be used to store data in a file. Depending on the nature of your data, I'd recommend looking into both the CSV and JSON libraries, which can help you read and write your data into a specific structure.

Answer (score 0):

To save in text file (every item in new line):

```
s = [1,2,3,4]
with open('listfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in s:
        f.write(f'{i}\n') #every item in new line
```

To load:

```
u_list = []
# open file and read the content in a list
with open('listfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # remove linebreak which is the last character of the string
        listitem = line[:-1]

        # add item to the list
        u_list.append(listitem)
```

Save as Json:

```
import json
s = [1,2,3,4]

file_name = input('Input file name: ')
json = json.dumps(s)
with open(file_name+".json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json)
```

to load:

```
lista = load_json()
```

Comment: That’s what i was looking for. Thank you very much!